# How to fix the "Program processor not available" error in integration test?

Tags: testing, program-test

Based on the code [here](https://github.com/0xnorman/solana-bootcamp-lectures/blob/master/echo-reference/tests/test.rs) I am trying to run an integration test using the `solana_program_test` crate.

The integration test code I am executing is as follows:

```
#![feature(backtrace)]
#![cfg(feature = "test-bpf")]
#[cfg(test)]
use {
    solana_program::{pubkey::Pubkey, system_program},
    solana_program_test::ProgramTest,
    solana_sdk::signature::{Keypair, Signer},
};

#[test]
fn test_echo() {
    let program_id = Pubkey::new_unique();
    let mut program_test = ProgramTest::default();
    program_test.add_program("echo", program_id, None);

    let auth = Keypair::new();
    program_test.add_account(
        auth.pubkey(),
        solana_sdk::account::Account {
            lamports: 100_000_000_000,
            data: vec![],
            owner: system_program::id(),
            ..solana_sdk::account::Account::default()
        },
    );
    // INSERT TESTS HERE
}
```

When I execute the test by running:

```
cargo test --package bpf-program-template --test integration_test test_echo --features "test-bpf" -- --exact
```

I get the following error:

```
-- snipped --

---- test_echo stdout ----
thread 'test_echo' panicked at 'Program processor not available for echo (4uQeVj5tqViQh7yWWGStvkEG1Zmhx6uasJtWCJziofM)', /Users/me/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-program-test-1.11.1/src/lib.rs:671:17
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

-- snipped --
```

Any idea on how to fix it? Could not get much info on the `solana_program_test` crate as it seems not to be documented that much.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the entry in the third argument of the `program_test.add_program` method as following:

```
let mut program = ProgramTest::default();
program.add_program("<program_name>", <program_name>::id(), processor!(<program_name>::entry));
```

Replace `<program_name>` with the name of your program, the one defined in `Cargo.toml > [package] > name`. In this case I think you can use "echo".

After the changes, execute using `cargo test-bpf`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to define the env variable BPF_OUT_DIR to the location of my .so file, and as my test program was adding multiple programs I made sure to include each one. I found this by reading here:
https://docs.rs/solana-program-test/latest/src/solana_program_test/lib.rs.html#415

example commands:

```
$ export BPF_OUT_DIR=/home/lando/projects/mpl/mpl/test-programs

$ pwd

/home/lando/projects/mpl/mpl/auction-house/program

$ cargo test --features='test-bpf' --test buy
```

success.

Answer (score 0):

Not all solana programs expose an entrypoint that works with ProcessInstructionWithContext. However, instead of

`cargo test`

you can use

`cargo test-sbf`

With `test-sbf` everything should work out of the box and you don't even need to call add_program on your ProgramTest instance.

I believe `cargo test-sbf` is the canonical way of running rust tests for solana programs at the moment, perhaps somebody wiser than me can comment on what it actually does under the hood.